# How to properly explicitly instantiate variadic template in template class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have template class for logging will cut it to show root of problem:

```
#ifndef LOGGER_HPP
#define LOGGER_HPP
#include "defines.hpp"

namespace Logger{

    template<typename logPolicy>
    class Logger{
        std::stringstream buffer;
        template<typename First, typename...Rest>
        void print_impl(First first, Rest...rest){
            buffer<<first;
            print_impl(rest...);
        }

        void print_impl(){
            policy->write(buffer.str());
            buffer.str("");
        }
    public:
        Logger(const std::string& fname): policy(nullptr){
        }

        template<Severity level, typename...Args>
        void print(Args...args){
            print_impl(args...);
        }

        ~Logger(){
            if(policy){
                policy->close();
                delete policy;
            }
        }
    };

}

#endif
```

I would like to move definition of that class to cpp file. I only need one object of that class of type FileLogPolicy, which would be instantiated explicitly in cpp file:

```
Logger<FileLogPolicy> logger("log.txt");
```

And use it like this:
`Logger::logger.print<DEBUG>("Exception happened", "bla bla bla")`;
Now instatiating template class without variadic template is easy, but with variadic template compiler expects me to provide specialization for every combination of argument types that print expects.
Can I instantiate template class with variadic template in cpp file? If so how?

Comment: You can use a complex macro to list all combinations you need. But this approach can work only with a finite set of combinations.

Comment: the use of variadic template parameters implies generic code. Generic code implies template expansion at the point of use. There's no reasonable way to pre-expand all possible types (and combinations of types) in a cpp file. Doing so will simply make the entire program brittle.